# My app crashes while clicking on a TextView

Tags: java, android, crash, textview, runtime-error

Whenever I run my application on my phone, it works fine and opens Correctly but as soon as I clicked the TextView for typing some text in that, The Application gets crashed. I got a similar post like this on the forum but It couldn't help me out. Don't know at all What actually happened. New in Android Platform. (please, Ask me if need something regarding Question)

> MainActivity.java

```
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void ButtonClicked(View view){

        EditText EnteredAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnteredAmount);
        Log.i("Amount Entered", EnteredAmount.getText().toString());
  }
```

> LogCat Error Log

```
       --------- beginning of crash
09-08 22:29:11.790 25239-25239/com.example.admin.convertcurrency E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.convertcurrency, PID: 25239
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickTextView(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'EnteredAmount'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)


    --------- beginning of system
09-08 22:29:11.858 25239-25239/com.example.admin.convertcurrency I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25239 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickTextView(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'EnteredAmount'
```

In your layout, you appear to have `android:onClick="clickTextView"`. In your activity, you do not have a method named `clickTextView()`. You need to implement that method in your activity:

```
public void clickTextView(View v) {
 // whatever you want to do
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `android:onClick="clickTextView"` attribute from your `<EditText>` in your layout resource.

Comment: @CommonWare I want to open the Keyboard after clicking the text view to enter something in that instead of crash, so what should I do for that?  I mean what will be the code for same?

Comment: @AniketJadhav if you want a TextView where you can enter text, you should be using EditText.

Comment: @AniketJadhav: If you use `EditText`, you do not need an `onClick` attribute. For devices that use a soft keyboard, the keyboard will appear automatically when the user clicks in the `EditText`.

Comment: @CommonsWare exactly, if there is inbuilt attribute of OnClick for text View then there no need to Implement extra method for TextView, and thats what i did in my code, Still not satisfied by your answer..!

Comment: @TheWanderer as you look at my code once agian, i already used EditText in it. Now where exactly issue lies

Comment: You need to remove `android:onClick="clickTextView"` from it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the multiple clickListener for views:

```
EditText EnteredAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnteredAmount);
EnteredAmount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I am clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about OnClickListener, may you please elaborate this attribute?

Comment: OnClickListener is an interface that is implemented on a class (Not so scary if you don't realize it the first time). The result is what I've shown above. It is that straightforward - listen for clicks on views (these can be buttons, textviews ... because they all extended the View class).
Here is some further guidance: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Comment: so is it same as the OnClick property or it is difference one? what i mean is,are OnClickListner and OnClick same things?

Comment: Yes they are the same. Its just that OnClickListener gives you more leeway in handling your click event.